# Is $E[E[Y_tZ_t|Y_t]|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}] = E[Y_tZ_t|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]$ where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the natural filtration process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

As the questions is stated in the topic. Let $Y_t$ and $Z_t$ be discrete time-dependent random variables, and $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the natural filtration such that we know everything that has happened up to to time t. Since the $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$ contains information about $Z_{t-1}$ as well, I am not sure if I could directly use the tower property here as $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$ is not a subset of $\sigma(Y_t)$ (the natural filtration generated by $Y_t$). The question is, can I use the following identity

$ E[Y_tZ_t|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}] = E[E[Y_tZ_t|Y_t]|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]$

If yes, why?

Comment: Double check your formatting, as you have a number of typographical errors.

Comment: No, try $(Y_t)$ independent and $Z_t=Y_{t-1}$.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid I had missed something there. However, I think i should be able to justify my problem by rather lettting $E[Y_tZ_t | Y_t, \mathcal{F}_{t-1}]$ as the inner expectation, where the identity should be right now.